# AFNETWORKING 3.0 Data Parameter Nil Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-3

I am getting the JSON back that I need, then I segue to another view controller to populate the data into a table view. The data populates, but the app crashes 2 minutes later with a data parameter is nil error.

Is there a way for me to stop the session from running after it completes? It appears to keep running non stop.

My header and implementation file code on pasteBin: https://pastebin.com/M11EF7Yp

```
 AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
NSDictionary *body = @{@"search": self.searchBar.text};
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:body options:0 error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


NSString *url = @"https://iosdevfitbody.herokuapp.com/fitbodylocations/search.json";

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:url parameters:nil error:nil];

 [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[[manager dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (!error) {
        if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            self.results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[responseObject objectForKey: @"message"]];
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@, %@, %@", error, response, responseObject);
    }
}]resume];
```

Comment: share full code please.

Comment: Please edit your question with formatted code so people can understand what you're trying to do. Just that part of the code doesn't help to understand your question.

Comment: Added pasteBin link